# Setting the title for Xterm with long paths

Tags: ksh, xterm

I have the following code in my .profile:

```
case $TERM in
    xterm*)
        HOST=`hostname`
        PS1='^[]0;${USER}@${HOST}: ${PWD}^Gksh$ '
        ;;
    *)
        PS1='ksh$ '
        ;;
esac
```

This works fine unless the path gets too long. Is there an alternative way of doing something similar but—when the paths are long—it displays `.../<end of the path>` so that it works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two alternatives, depending on your end goal.

### Only show the trailing directory element

```
PS1='^[]0;${USER}@${HOST}: ${PWD##*/}^Gksh$ '
```

This simply introduces the `##` parameter substitution to your existing PS1 in order to greedily strip away characters until the final forward slash. This will shorten the `PWD` portion of the PS1 prompt string regardless of length.

### Only shorten long PWD strings

Full disclosure, I got the "bones" of this from one of the answers to this Stack Overflow question:

[How to custom display prompt in KornShell to show hostname and current directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1171663/how-to-custom-display-prompt-in-kornshell-to-show-hostname-and-current-directory)

... then modified it accordingly. In short, it aliases `cd` to an internal function. That function emulates the original `cd` behavior but then does some string "math" to determine the new PS1 prompt. I took your question rather literally, so if you don't want "..." prefixing the long directory names, remove that string from the `P=...` line and also remove the `+3` in the math line above it.

```
function _cd {
   directory=$1
   pattern=$2

   # First cd to the directory
   if [ "$pattern" ]
   then
       \cd "$directory" "$pattern"
   elif [ "$directory" ]
   then
       \cd "$directory"
   else
       \cd
   fi

   # set this value to taste
   MAXLEN=20
   LEN=${#PWD}
   P=$PWD
   # if PWD is "too" long, trim it
   if [ $LEN -gt $MAXLEN ]
   then
     # the 3 is for the literal "..."
     START=$(( LEN - MAXLEN + 3 ))
     P="..."$(echo $PWD | cut -c ${START}-)
   fi
   PS1="^[]0;${USER}@${HOST}: $P^Gksh\$ "
}

alias cd="_cd"
```

Of course, as I write this up, a third option comes to mind -- to use the alias/internal-function code, but instead of `cut`ing the string, use the `##` parameter substitution in it to strip directory elements as in the first example.

Answer (score 0):

The best way that I have found is to use a ksh93 discipline function on the PS1 environmental variable:

```
# set ksh prompt and xterm title
_PSX='$( p="${PWD/~(El)${HOME}/\~}"
     printf "%s@%s:%s" "${LOGNAME}" "$(hostname -s)" "${p}"
)'

function PS1.get
{
    .sh.value="ESC]0;${_PSX}^G${_PSX}$ " 
}
```